# Html Video player plays sound but not video

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, html5-video

Im in the process of making a webpage, and im trying to insert a video. The video player loads fine, and you can press play, but only the audio plays, not the video. (When previewing in chrome)
When viewing in firefox it works properly

My code is as follows...

```
<video width="600" height="400" controls>
  <source src="ds2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="ds2.ogv" type="video/ogv">
  <source src="ds2.webm" type="video/webm">
```

Your browser does not support the video tag.

```
</video>
```

My Doctype is `<!Doctype html>`

I checked the MIME type, its Video/mp4. however, one of the mime requests is in red and cancelled (When checking with google dev tools networking)

Im using microsoft expression web 4 (incase it is relevant)

If i've neglected any important information please let me know and ill update the post :) Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: If you open the video file in the browser directly, does it have audio?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your problem is with the file encoding. HTML5 supports very few types and, sadly, every browser can play only part of this narrow list.

If you convert your mp4 file to `H.264` encoding it will work on chrome and IE9 and above, but  apparently due to patent issues, firefox does not support it but will play it if the OS can play it. This is really annoying and still require the use of players in order to play files in not-supported browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, I will try converting to H.264 tomorrow morning and update you :)

Comment: Thank you! Worked for me as well. Finally somebody knows the real reason behind it. This answer is better than any of those that recommend setting a fixed width or using other plugins since they actually didn't work for me neither.

Comment: is .h.264 the extension for H.264 files or is it flv, or is it neither??

Comment: not the extension but the codec thats different thing