# How to load video in my website

Tags: html, video

I have a website where I am trying to show a video.I have 2 mp4 format videos and both are ok(not corrupted).When I try to show these two using  tag in html5 one is working but another is not working.
I have used the code given below

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="video/v1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="video/v1.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>


<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="video/theme.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="video/theme.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

here,in firefox first one is working great but the next one shows the error "No video with supported format and mime type found".In chrome first one is ok and second one only shows audio.
Please help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Had the same problem. Try to convert your videos with FormatFactory or another software and change the "Video Encode" parameter to "AVC(H264)"; It solves my problems, it's maybe the same reason for you.

Comment: I am sorry,what do u mean by three formats?Please make me clear #Ms. Nobody.Yeah both the videos are in the same directory.

Comment: I suggest you use jwplayer it is responsive for several browser, I have also use on my projects. Its free... www.jwplayer.com

Comment: How can I use jwplayer #Ayaz Shah?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if `video/theme.mp4` is accessible in the browser. View source and try clicking the link or see if it is loaded in the resources in the development tools. It sounds like Firefox can't find/read `theme.mp4` or `theme.ogg` so is displaying the error message. Chrome can't find `theme.mp4` either but is reading it's MIME Type it as `audio/ogg` rather than `video/ogg`.

You could try this page and see if it helps, the MDN always has useful stuff:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Comment: I have tried this.For the first v1.mp4 i have found the video from view video.but for theme.mp4 I haven't found and object is not found shows.For both videos I have no .ogg format.So why then v1.mp4 shows http://localhost/rmp/video/v1.mp4 when I visit view video and http://localhost/rmp/video/theme.ogg for theme.mp4? #luc122c

Comment: Because you have written the `.mp4` first it will try that first, if it can't read that, then it will fall back to the `.ogg` you specified. If it is playing `theme.ogg`, something is wrong with `theme.mp4`

Comment: Well then what should i do #luc122c?

Comment: I would try moving the .mp4 to a new directory, creating a new link to it and trying it there too. If that works, then the link was wrong. 

Or try a different video with a different name in the same location and change the link. If this works then the video is broken.

Comment: In my localhost it shows the same error.Besides my first and second videos are in the same directory #luc122c

Comment: Have you tried the advice in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325358/html-video-player-plays-sound-but-not-video?rq=1](this thread)?

Comment: Both videos play fine for me in safari. Both in .mp4. However neither work in Firefox. Have you tried just using `<!DOCTYPE html>`without the DTD

Comment: Yeah I have tried but the same problem occurs.I have first video working but not the last one bro. :'(