# ASP.NET Web API: Video steaming not working on chrome and very slow on other browsers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

**What I am trying to do?**

I am trying to create a video streaming website using ASP.net web API.

**Problem**

The api is working fine when running on local but when uploaded on live server then it does not play on chrome at all and too slow on firefox, opera

[Live Demo of Problem](http://demo.rpgindia.co.in/temp/index.html)
Please open this link in Chrome, firefox and you will see the difference.

*Note: Live Demo link will be available till the problem is solved then I will remove it*

[GitHub link of source code](https://github.com/vikasbnsl/videoSteamer)

Please download the code from Github and in its `videos` folder please put a **mp4** file of size at least 700mb or more
Please name it `avan.mp4`

Here is the code that I am using:

**Coding part here**

Code Credits: [Robert Vandenberg Huang: `Codeproject`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820146/HTTP-Partial-Content-In-ASP-NET-Web-API-Video)

Those who can not download the code from GitHub, I am providing everything here

**Index.html**

```
<video id="mainPlayer" width="640" height="360"
       autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" onloadeddata="onLoad()">
    <source src="api/media/play?f=avan.mp4" />
</video>
```

**Web API Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace VideoLIb.Controllers
{

    //http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820146/HTTP-Partial-Content-In-ASP-NET-Web-API-Video
    public class MediaController : ApiController
    {
        #region Fields

        // This will be used in copying input stream to output stream.
        public const int ReadStreamBufferSize = 1024 * 512;//* 1024;
        // We have a read-only dictionary for mapping file extensions and MIME names. 
        public static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> MimeNames;
        // We will discuss this later.
        public static readonly IReadOnlyCollection<char> InvalidFileNameChars;
        // Where are your videos located at? Change the value to any folder you want.
        public static readonly string InitialDirectory;

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        static MediaController()
        {
            var mimeNames = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            mimeNames.Add(".mp3", "audio/mpeg");    // List all supported media types; 
            mimeNames.Add(".mp4", "video/mp4");
            mimeNames.Add(".ogg", "application/ogg");
            mimeNames.Add(".ogv", "video/ogg");
            mimeNames.Add(".oga", "audio/ogg");
            mimeNames.Add(".wav", "audio/x-wav");
            mimeNames.Add(".webm", "video/webm");

            MimeNames = new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>(mimeNames);

            InvalidFileNameChars = Array.AsReadOnly(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars());
            InitialDirectory = @"~/videos"; /// directory that contains videos
        }

        #endregion

        #region Actions
        //http://localhost:58720/
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Play(string f)
        {
            // This can prevent some unnecessary accesses. 
            // These kind of file names won't be existing at all. 
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f) || AnyInvalidFileNameChars(f))
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

            var mappedPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(Path.Combine(InitialDirectory, f));
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(mappedPath);

            if (!fileInfo.Exists)
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

            long totalLength = fileInfo.Length;

            RangeHeaderValue rangeHeader = base.Request.Headers.Range;
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

            response.Headers.AcceptRanges.Add("bytes");

            // The request will be treated as normal request if there is no Range header.
            if (rangeHeader == null || !rangeHeader.Ranges.Any())
            {
                response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
                response.Content = new PushStreamContent((outputStream, httpContent, transpContext)
                =>
                {
                    using (outputStream) // Copy the file to output stream straightforward. 
                    using (Stream inputStream = fileInfo.OpenRead())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            inputStream.CopyTo(outputStream, ReadStreamBufferSize);
                        }
                        catch (Exception error)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(error);
                        }
                    }
                }, GetMimeNameFromExt(fileInfo.Extension));

                response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = totalLength;
                return response;
            }

            long start = 0, end = 0;

            // 1. If the unit is not 'bytes'.
            // 2. If there are multiple ranges in header value.
            // 3. If start or end position is greater than file length.
            if (rangeHeader.Unit != "bytes" || rangeHeader.Ranges.Count > 1 ||
                !TryReadRangeItem(rangeHeader.Ranges.First(), totalLength, out start, out end))
            {
                response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.RequestedRangeNotSatisfiable;
                response.Content = new StreamContent(Stream.Null);  // No content for this status.
                response.Content.Headers.ContentRange = new ContentRangeHeaderValue(totalLength);
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = GetMimeNameFromExt(fileInfo.Extension);

                return response;
            }

            var contentRange = new ContentRangeHeaderValue(start, end, totalLength);

            // We are now ready to produce partial content.
            response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.PartialContent;
            response.Content = new PushStreamContent((outputStream, httpContent, transpContext)
            =>
            {
                using (outputStream) // Copy the file to output stream in indicated range.
                using (Stream inputStream = fileInfo.OpenRead())
                    CreatePartialContent(inputStream, outputStream, start, end);

            }, GetMimeNameFromExt(fileInfo.Extension));

            response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = end - start + 1;
            response.Content.Headers.ContentRange = contentRange;

            return response;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Others

        private static bool AnyInvalidFileNameChars(string fileName)
        {
            return InvalidFileNameChars.Intersect(fileName).Any();
        }

        private static MediaTypeHeaderValue GetMimeNameFromExt(string ext)
        {
            string value;

            if (MimeNames.TryGetValue(ext.ToLowerInvariant(), out value))
                return new MediaTypeHeaderValue(value);
            else
                return new MediaTypeHeaderValue(MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
        }

        private static bool TryReadRangeItem(RangeItemHeaderValue range, long contentLength,
            out long start, out long end)
        {
            if (range.From != null)
            {
                start = range.From.Value;
                if (range.To != null)
                    end = range.To.Value;
                else
                    end = contentLength - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                end = contentLength - 1;
                if (range.To != null)
                    start = contentLength - range.To.Value;
                else
                    start = 0;
            }
            return (start < contentLength && end < contentLength);
        }

        private static void CreatePartialContent(Stream inputStream, Stream outputStream,
            long start, long end)
        {
            int count = 0;
            long remainingBytes = end - start + 1;
            long position = start;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[ReadStreamBufferSize];

            inputStream.Position = start;
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    if (remainingBytes > ReadStreamBufferSize)
                        count = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, ReadStreamBufferSize);
                    else
                        count = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)remainingBytes);
                    outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(error);
                    break;
                }
                position = inputStream.Position;
                remainingBytes = end - position + 1;
            } while (position <= end);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to give it a look....

Comment: I have it working here: http://video-test.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Here is the repo: https://github.com/AshWilliams/VideoPlayerTest

Comment: I include another player for comparison purposes...

Comment: Dear @Hackerman, first of all, many thanks for sparing time for the issue. I have replaced all your code on my server but nothing changed (still not playing on chrome and too slow on firefox). `http://demo.rpgindia.co.in/` this is the link and all code is yours , you can yourself see that videos are still not getting played and the current video is of size 700 mb. I apologise for the late reply, I hope you understand that there is a Timezone difference.

Comment: Maybe there is some encoding issues with your video....as you see my test  on azure works fine....please check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325358/html-video-player-plays-sound-but-not-video

Comment: @Hackerman `http://demo.rpgindia.co.in/videos/avan.mp4` if I am opening the video directly then it is getting played