# Audio is playing but video missing in some video not in all in core php

Tags: javascript, php

```
<video id="myVideo_<?php echo $f2['id']; ?>" controls controlsList="nodownload" width="100%" >
    <source id="mp4Source" src="uploads/<?php echo $f2['file_path'] ?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Only 3 videos are only playing audio not video out of 25 videos is there any browser issue in it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325358/html-video-player-plays-sound-but-not-video

Comment: The <source> element allows you to specify alternative video files which the browser may choose from. The browser will use the first recognized format.

Comment: @pradeep why it play other 22 videos then ??

Comment: other videos all run on the same pattren

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov sir it mean i need to convert my 25 videos into h.264 format ??

Comment: Yes! exactly.....

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov i am not able to understand why it run my other 22 videos ..... they are also using mp4 extension

Comment: Check the content type of the file: `mime_content_type('video.mp4')`. Might be your file is corrupted!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html Video player plays sound but not video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325358/html-video-player-plays-sound-but-not-video)

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov sir i wana add one more thing that these videos are working fine a little time ago but now it dont show the videos

Comment: thnx @SalimIbrogimov  solution resolved by just uploading video again after changing mp4 version into mp4 version again

Comment: @amirishaque: great!